# Manipulating searched object(child) in (parent)model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my model `subject.rb` i have the following defined

```
has_many :tutors, through: :profiles    

  def self.search(param)
    where("name like ?", "%#{param}%")
  end
```

So something like `Subject.search("English")` works perfectly fine in rails console.

What i would like to know is that if i do `subject = Subject.first` and i can do stuff like `subject.id` and it returns the subject ID to me.

Whereas when i do `subject = Subject.search("English")` i am unable to do something like `subject.id`

Because i'm trying to link the search function to my `tutor.rb` model with the following code.

```
def self.subject_search(s)
  @tutor = Tutor.all
  @tutor.each do |x|
    y = x.subjects.search(s)
    unless y.empty?
      return x
    end
  end
end
```

Which works but only returns one Tutor and not all Tutors that have the subject.

I also tried this instead

```
def self.subject_search(s)
    @subject = Subject.search(s)
    if @subject
      @subject.tutors 
    end
  end
```

But thats when i realised @subject.tutors doesn't work, as explained above, if i do `subject = Subject.search("English")` i can't manipulate `subject` with any methods.

What am i doing wrongly?

Comment: You can find error yourself, if you try to show Subject.search("English").class != Model Subject but Array or ...

Comment: Yes i'm aware that when i do `Subject.search("English")` it says something along the lines of ActiveRecord_Relation. But what i do not understand is what i should be doing instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `#where` returns an array of objects meeting the criteria.

`Subject.search('Math') => ['Math1', 'Math2', 'Math3'] # Objects of course`

In your case, you should be doing `Subject.find_by_name('English')` which returns the first object satisfying your query. Then you can call `#tutors` on your `Subject` model assuming you have the method defined.

If you do have to use the `like` operator no matter what (which I do not recommend), here's what will happen.

```
s = Subject.search('En') # => ['English', 'Environmental Science', ..]
s.tutors # => Undefined method tutors for Array class
```

Here, `s` is an array of `Subject` models rather than a singular `Subject` which is the reason why its not working. You either need something to narrow it down more or loop through it which is probably not what you want anyway.

Comment: I don't quite understand your answer. Do you think you could elaborate? I dont understand why `Subject.find("English")` would work too.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `Subject.find_by_name('English')`. I've updated my answer

Comment: Again, as I mentioned, the `find` method returns only one object whereas the `where` method returns an array of objects satisfying the condition. The only downside is that you cannot do something like `Subject.find_by_name('Englis')` and expect a result.

Comment: cool its working perfectly now! thanks so much. I defined the method directly in my Tutor model as 
`def self.subject_search(s)
   @subject = Subject.find_by_name(s)
   unless @subject.nil?
     @subject.tutors
   end
 end`